# Activerecord "where" condition for Array attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have model `course.rb` with `pre_courses` is an array.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :pre_courses, Array
end
```

Now I want to check if an exist `course` is `pre_course` of any course by Activerecord or raw SQL (I am using MySQL), such as `Course.where("pre_courses INCLUDEs self.id`").

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `Course.where(" '#{self.id}'  = ANY (pre_courses)")`

Comment: Try this `Course.includes(:pre_courses).where.not(pre_courses: {id: nil} ") ` or `Course.includes(:pre_courses).where.not(pre_courses: {id: nil} ").find(self.id)`

Comment: Your first step should really be to replace `serialize` with a separate table.

Comment: Queries with `LIKE` tend to be very slow with many columns and are hard to optimize. As soon as I need to query by a serialized data column with `LIKE` I would consider another data structure: Perhaps a [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) or a normalized table structure.

Answer (score 2):

A serialized array is just a string in the db, so try using `LIKE`, for example:

```
Course.where("pre_courses LIKE ?", "% #{self.id}\n%")
```

Notice that a serialzed array adds a space before each item and a new line after, thus the added space before the interpolated string and the `\n` at the end.

Comment: What happens if `21` is in the YAMLized array but you're searching for `2`?

Comment: @muistooshort That specific case shouldn't be a problem, because of the `\n` after `2`;  but it will be for any number that ends with `2`. So a space must be added before the number; i'll update the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a `pre_course` is actually a regular `course`, a `course` can have many `pre_courses` and a `pre_course` can belong to many `courses`. A self referential `has_many through` relationship is possible and may give you more flexibility to work with your data than serializing it as an array.

You'll need a join model I'll call `CoursePreCourse`. It will have the columns `course_id` and `pre_course_id`. `pre_course_id` will be a foreign key for records on the `courses` table.

```
class CreateCoursePreCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :course_pre_courses do |t|
      t.references :course, foreign_key: true
      t.references :pre_course, foreign_key: { to_table: :courses }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CoursePreCourse < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :pre_course, class_name: 'Course'
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  # A straight-forward has_many :through association for a course that has_many :pre_courses
  has_many :course_pre_courses
  has_many :pre_courses, through: :course_pre_courses

  # A little coercion is necessary to set up the association as a pre_course that has_many :courses
  has_many :pre_course_courses, class_name: 'CoursePreCourse', foreign_key: :pre_course_id
  has_many :courses, through: :pre_course_courses
end
```

Now you can retrieve the `courses` that are `pre_courses` of any `course` with `course.pre_courses`. If you want to see if a `course` is a `pre_course` of other `courses` it's `pre_course.courses`. Similarly you can add a `course` to another `course`'s `pre_courses` with either `course.pre_courses << pre_course` or `pre_course.courses << course`.

Do you ever say a word so many times it loses its meaning?